# How can I prevent the Finder from jumping to Desktop1 after logout?

Tags: finder, big-sur, desktop

I have two displays on my macbook pro 15 (OSX 11.5.2).

On display1 is desktop1 and on display2 is desktop2 + 3.
I open finder on desktop2. But after logout and new login everytime finder is on desktop1.

How can I fix my finder on desktop2?

Comment: Why do you logout? Wouldn't it be faster for you to restart exactly where you were in less than 5 seconds with a simple [ctrl][cmd][q] ( = Lock Screen ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check this works when you have "Displays have separate Spaces" set, but it ought to work if you set Finder to the Space you want it, then right click in the Dock > Options > This Desktop.

[image]